RabbitMQ with Jackson2JsonMessageConverter double encodes the string
I configured my RabbitMQ to use the following message converter: Jackson2JsonMessageConverter. However, it created a problem: when the producer sends message as a JSON String, the consumer received this String double-encoded.
Example:
The string sent by producer:     "message": "Hello World!" 
The string received by consumer: "\"message\": \"Hello World!\""

What I tried:
One of the solutions is to remove the Jackson2JsonMessageConverter from my RabbitMQ configuration, however I need Jackson2JsonMessageConverter because one of my other producers sends List<List<MyObject>> to the queue, and I want to be able to deserialize it. So, removing Jackson2JsonMessageConverter is not going to be a valid solution for me.

RabbitMQConfig.java:
package dev.abu.screener_backend.rabbitmq;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jacksonConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jacksonConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}

Methods from RabbitMQService.java to create queues, consumers and listeners:
public void createQueue(String queueName) {
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(new Queue(queueName, false, true, true));
}

public void createConsumer(String queueName) {
        DirectMessageListenerContainer container = new DirectMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(getListener());
        container.start();
    }

public MessageListener getListener() {
        return (Message message) -> {
            String payload = new String(message.getBody());
            System.out.println(payload); 
            // and doing something here with payload ...
        };
}

And finally, this is how my producers sends a message to a queue:
String data =
        """
        "message": "Hello World!"
        """; // this is example json
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, data);

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!

The String you send is not even a proper string, it has not quotes around. So when you receive it as your are not configuring anything and ask to wrap it in a String then you obtain the quotes around the body. You should really review your format and send json for example

@Chasca even when I provide a valid JSON string, the issue was still there. Moreover, in the code I provided above, I just hardcoded a json string for clarity, but in my actual program, I receive a json response from a third-party WebSocket, and send this data to a Rabbit Queue.

After a while, the requirements have changed in my application, and now I need to send two string values into a queue as a String array. Because of this, the issue described in the original post has been resolved.
Here is my updated producer:
// some code above..
String symbol = "abc";
String payload = "{\"message\": \"hello world\"}"; // it is just example, the real payload is different and is not hardcoded. 
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, new String[]{symbol, payload});

Here, the symbol is just some value, while the payload is a real json string.
And this is how my consumer extracts this data:
public MessageListener getListener() {
    return (Message message) -> {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String[] data = mapper.readValue(message.getBody(), new TypeReference<>() {});
            String symbol = data[0];
            String payload = data[1]; // now the payload is decoded correctly
            // ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ...
        }
    };
}

I hope it helps someone who also had this problem.
